# Relations on Stiefel-Whitney classes

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, characteristic-classes

Can arbitrary cohomology classes $w_1,\dots,w_n$ from $H^{*}(B,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ be Stiefel-Whitney classes of some bundle over the given base $B$ or there are some necessary relation which can be obtained from topology of $B$?

In particular, I'm interseted in real bundles over $S^1\times S^1$ and $S^1\times S^1\times S^1$

Answer (score 3):

There are many relations that hold universally involving [Steenrod operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel%E2%80%93Whitney_class#Relations_over_the_Steenrod_algebra); in fact the Stiefel-Whitney classes are generated under the action of the Steenrod operations by the classes $w_{2^i}$. This implies, in particular, that the first nonvanishing Stiefel-Whitney class must have index a power of $2$, so for example if $w_1 = w_2 = 0$ then it necessarily follows that $w_3 = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on what you consider as a "relation". There are no nontrivial polynomial relations between them, which hold universally, as one can see by calculating the $\mathbf{Z}/2 \mathbf{Z}$-cohomology algebra of $BO(n)$, which is a polynomial algebra in the Stiefel-Whitney classes.

An elementary reference for this calculation is the book of Milnor and Stasheff.

Comment: @yuch For the torus it is true. The Chern class of the complex line bundle corresponding to the generator of H2(T;Z) projects to the non-zero second Stiefel-Whitney class. The first S-W class is 0 because the bundle is orientable. By a general theorem, each element of H^1 over Z2 is the first S-W class of a real line bundle. Whitney sums of these line bundles produces 2 plane bundles with non-zero second S-W-class and arbitrary 1'st S-W class. These line bundles are flat bundles obtained as quotients of TxR by rotations by 180 degrees on T and negation of R.